# how do I replace a word in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to practice some JavaScript, and I ran into a problem which is why the splice method is working not quite how I want it to work, so here's the challenge that I went for:

so I should write a function that reverses all the words in a sentence that start with a particular letter.

example:

```
specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s")
➞ "word sehcraes are repus fun"
```

actually I understood the exercice and I started solving it but the problem is I knew the words that should be reversed and I reversed them as you see here:

```js
function specialReverse(s, c) {
  var words = s.split(" ");
  words.findIndex(i => {
    if (i[0] === c) {
      var newWords = i.split("").reverse().join("");
      words.splice(i[0] === c, 1, newWords, i)
    }
  })
  return words
}
console.log(
  specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s")
)
```

but my problem that I couldn't replace the previous words (searches and super) I think my problem is with splice because the result when I run that code is this:
[image]

I don't know why the word "searches" get replicated several time I think my problem is coming from the splice() method

Comment: @ med same logic made into a simple way with the help of es6 methods and unwanted return to make it single line. Check the answer

Comment: @ med added the correction part based on the question and explained it. Kindly check

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) ,rather than going with findIndex

```js
//specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s")
//"word sehcraes are repus fun"

function reverse(sentence, letter) {

  let _ar = sentence.split(/(\s+)/);

  return _ar.map(ele => {
    if (ele.startsWith(letter)) {

      ele = ele.split("").reverse().join("");
    }

    return ele;
  }).join("");


}

console.log(reverse("word searches are super fun", "s"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your question when you find the character starts with the character that you have passed through the function you need to replace the existing array word.

```
.splice(startingIndex, numDeletions, replacement1, replacement2, ... )
```

correction

`words.splice(i[0] === c, 1, newWords, i)` the first parameter should be the index of the word that you have found the string where it starts with passed character, here its a boolean value.

So you can use the second argument of `findIndex(item, index)` and get the index. See the below updated snippet.

```js
function specialReverse(s, c) {
  var words = s.split(" ");
  words.findIndex((item, index) => {
    if (item[0] === c) {
      var newWords = item.split("").reverse().join("");
      words.splice(index, 1, newWords)
    }
  })
  return words.join(" ")
}
console.log(
  specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s")
)
```

**ALTERNATE SIMPLE WAY**

A simple and one liner, basically you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) mainly to get the desired result.

Logical is simple return a new reversed words with char having, join them. and if the word has char that passed reverse it else return the word

Check the below snippet

```js
const specialReverse = (str, char) =>  str.split(" ").map(word => 
   word.startsWith(char) ? word.split("").reverse().join("") : word
).join(" ")


console.log(specialReverse("words searches are super fun", "s"))
```

Comment: basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855496/295783 once fixed to use startWith

Comment: what is the diff it make, and why @mplungjan includes has been replaced with startsWith, also does all the browsers support startsWith ?

Comment: The same browsers that support includes support startsWith. Take your code, leave the "words" I changed from "word" and see it will ALSO takes that because it INCLUDES "s" even it does not startsWith "s"

Answer (score 0):

you can split the words and then look for the words to reverse

```
function reverseWord(word) {
  var reversed = "";
  for (var i = word.length - 1; i >=0; --i) {
    reversed += word.charAt(i);
  }
  return reversed;
}

function specialReverse(words, ch) {
   return words.split(/\s+/).map(function(word) {
      return word.startsWith(ch) ? reverseWord(word) : word;
   }).join(" ");
}

console.log(specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
function specialReverse(s, c) {
  let words = s.split(" ");
  words.find((element, index) => {
    if (element[0] === c) {
      let newWords = element.split("").reverse().join("");
      words[index] = newWords; //Replaces the value of that particular index
    }
  })
  return words
}
let x = specialReverse("word searches are super fun", "s")
console.log(x)
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/5cax2j39/)

Comment: How? @mplungjan

Comment: Why do you not allow the snippet to stay. Why do we HAVE to go to JSFiddle when we can stay here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```js
const reverseWord = word => word.split("").reverse().join("")

const reverseIfChar = (sentence, c) => sentence.split(" ")
  .map(word => word.startsWith(c) ? reverseWord(word) : word)
  .join(" ")

console.log(reverseIfChar("abc dfg 010", 'd'))
```